# Are i.i.d. random variables always associated with a distribution function?

Tags: distributions, variance, mean, expected-value, iid

It is known that independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables are mutually independent and each random variable has the **same probability distribution** as the others.

However, is it possible to assume i.i.d. random variables *without* specifying the distribution function? Let me explain using the following example.

If $X_i,i=1,2,...n$ is an i.i.d. random variable, then expectation of $X_i$, $E(X_i)=\mu$ and $E(X_i^2)-E(X_i)^2 = \sigma^2$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are the mean and variance, respectively.

Will these definitions hold true when the distribution function is not specified?

**[EDIT]**

As Martijn Weterings pointed out, my main concern is:

Whether $E(X_i)$ is the *mean* and $E(X_i^2)−E(X_i)^2$ is the *variance* when the distribution function is not specified?

Comment: There would always be a distribution function, whether it is specified or not.

Comment: What derivations? If you don't specify the distribution like to you did (seems to be Gaussian), then you can't say what the mean and variance is. But it always holds that $VAR(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you gave the definitions, instead of derivations.

Comment: *"If $X$ denotes an i.i.d random variable"* this sentence is a bit strange (i.i.d. is more like a relation between two variables rather than a property of a variable).

Comment: "Will these derivations hold true...?" what does that 'these derivations' mean? Do you wonder whether $E(X)$ is the mean and $E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ is the variance, also when the distribution function is not specified? This explicit question seems to be about variables in general, so what is the specific problem with i.i.d. variables?

Comment: @user158565 I have some revisions to the question. Hope it clarifies the confusion.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I have rephrased the texts in question. Hope the revised texts clarify the confusion.

Comment: @nashynash, It is still confusing what your question is. Is it about the definitions of mean (the [first raw moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Mean)) and variance (the [second central moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Variance)) or is it about identical and independent distributed variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are associated with a distribution. It's in the name that they are *identically distributed*.

You gave the definition of the mean of a random variable and an immediate consequence of the definition of variance. These equations are true for all distributions that have first and second [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)). (Thanks @scortchi for the correction).

Comment: (+1) But not true for e.g. a Cauchy r.v. - the moments need to exist.

Comment: In a sort of sense, you could still define those moments even when they do not exist. They will just be vacuous truths.